# Perl Code Error: Global Symbol Requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I am trying to compile this code, but it keeps getting same error for @fields and $element variable. As far as I can tell it is not an scoping error, as it is declared globally. It gets compiled if I don't use strict.

I have provided a prototype of code, please ignore any typing errors.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use file::BaseName;
use file::Copy;

#my array declaration
my @fields;

#my other declarations
#input and output file initialization

while(<DATA1>) {
    $String='';
    $String= $_;
    @fields= split(/,/,$String);
        foreach my $elements(@fields){
             #Some code
         }

    #more code
}
close (DATA1);
```

Comment: What's the error? What's in `DATA1`? Where do you declare `$String`?

Comment: This looks like a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37856440/1331451.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because we cannot debug code that we do not see. You need to include **your real code** by [edit]ing and copy/pasting the actual, real, live code. Do not type it in again. Do not post something else. Show the real code. No-one can guess what you typed wrong on your computer.

Comment: In other declarations.

Comment: Oh okay Thanks..! I thought it must be some scoping error I cant see..!

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. When we say `use strict;` and `use warnings;` we mean "...And fix the problems they report". They're not breaking your code - they're just telling you about problems in advance, rather than when you'll take a week to debug them.

Comment: There might be - but we can't see it _either_ because you haven't provided the code that's breaking. Or the error. IN THE EXAMPLE you haven't declared: `$String`, nor have you opened the `DATA1` filehandle.

Comment: As I said to you yesterday, one of the most important attributes that a programmer needs is attention to detail. There is at least one of the points in [yesterday's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37861323/7231) which you haven't fully addressed. `file::Basename` is not the same as `File::Basename`. I repeat my advice from yesterday - take more care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a bare minimum, you need to get your code to compile.  The perl compiler is usually very helpful in telling you what is wrong.  Here you have invalid package names, an invalid perl path, and you should use DATA instead of DATA1.

Try running your code using `diagnostics` as it is more informative:

```
perl -cwT -Mdiagnostics script.pl

Can't locate file/BaseName.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
file::BaseName module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/i386-
... ) at foo2.pl line 4.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at foo2.pl line 4 (#1)
    (F) You said to do (or require, or use) a file that couldn't be found.
    Perl looks for the file in all the locations mentioned in @INC, unless
    the file name included the full path to the file.  Perhaps you need
    to set the PERL5LIB or PERL5OPT environment variable to say where the
    extra library is, or maybe the script needs to add the library name
    to @INC.  Or maybe you just misspelled the name of the file.

    See "require" in perlfunc and lib.

Uncaught exception from user code:
    Can't locate file/BaseName.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
    file::BaseName module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/i386-
    ... ) at foo2.pl line 4.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at foo2.pl line 4.
```

Here is a compiling version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;

my @fields;

while(<DATA>) {
    my $String='';
    $String= $_;
    @fields= split(/,/,$String);
    my $i = 0;
    foreach my $element (@fields) {
        print "[$i] : $element\n";
        $i++;
    }
}

__DATA__
foo,bar,baz
qux,1,2,3
```

**Output**

```
[0] : foo
[1] : bar
[2] : baz

[0] : qux
[1] : 1
[2] : 2
[3] : 3
```

Comment: *"you should use DATA instead of DATA1"* Not necessarily, if `DATA1` has been opened in the invisible parts of the program

Comment: True, but http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html says that perl will know how to read the `__DATA__` section.  Any other section will require opening specially.  If using multiple data blocks, you should consider using `Inline::Files` http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Inline-Files-0.69/lib/Inline/Files.pm

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're making. The OP may not have intended to use a data block at all

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have skipped an awful lot of code where issues may be hidden

In what you *have* shown

- You haven't declared `$String`, which should really be `$string`
- `file::BaseName` is really called `File::Basename`, and `file::Copy` is spelled `File::Copy`
- `#!usr/bin/perl` should be `#!/usr/bin/perl`
- `@fields` should be declared where it is first used, not at the outer level of the file

However, because there is so much missing these may not be the source of your error

Try rewriting this part of your code like so

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;

# my array declaration
my @fields;

# my other declarations
# input and output file initialization

while ( <DATA1> ) {

    my $string = $_;

    @fields = split /,/, $string;

    foreach my $elements ( @fields ) {
        # Some code
    }

    # REST OF THE CODE

}

close DATA1;
```